# is the a machine learning api for combining words into a sentence

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, google-natural-language

There are many machine learning api for scanning images but they just return a bunch of tags.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

```
{ "tags": [ "train", "platform", "station", "building", "indoor", "subway", "track", "walking", "waiting", "pulling", "board", "people", "man", "luggage", "standing", "holding", "large", "woman", "yellow", "suitcase" ],  "confidence": 0.833099365 } ] }
```

Are there any apis for combining these into a sentence?
MS Cognitive Vision is the only one that produces a full caption

```
"captions": [ { "text": "people waiting at a train station",
```

Google sentiment analysis can split a sentence into grammar parts but is there any api that does the reverse?

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/basics

```
INPUT:
"train", "platform", "station", "building", "indoor", "subway", "track", "walking", "waiting", "pulling", "board", "people",
 "man", "luggage", "standing", "holding", "large", "woman", "yellow", "suitcase"

OUTPUT:
"people waiting at a train station"
```

Comment: Is the caption that's returned from the Computer Vision API not what you need?

Comment: MS was just an example  and it limits you to the ms api. Other apis can retrieve text from a picture but  text is often split into chunks. I just need api to put them into cohesive sentence. I'm looking at grammar ML apis as well.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but are you not able to use the MS API since that does return a caption?

Comment: probably my question is how do MS do it? are there other APIs.

Comment: In regards to how MS does it, for their Cognitive Services APIs they build their models from [CNTK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/).

Comment: @brian.clear What if dog was in a picture and API generate "Dog was waiting for train at a station." just guessing :)